# open stream: permission denied in php laravel running on windows

Tags: php, laravel

Error message I get

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelops\laravel-meetup\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelops\laravel-meetup\bootstrap\autoload.php on
>   line 17
>
> line 17 of autoload.php
>
> require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

whats the reason for this error.

Comment: Did you install your `composer` dependencies prior to running your app? If not please run `composer install` first.

Comment: yes the composer and dependencies were insalled already

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload`. Then `composer update --no-scripts` and see if the errors pops up again.

Comment: i tried `composer dump-autoload` and when i ran `composer update --no-scripts` it says `--no-script` option not available.  is there any other solutions please let me know

Comment: Can you please verify if `autoload.php` file is there in your `vendor` directory?

Comment: thanks the `composer dump-autoload` followed by a `composer update` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just run this command after that add .env file to your projet

```
composer update --no-scripts
```